# running parallel function with different inputs being trasnformed in the same input

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I'm trying to run parellel functions with async.js

But when I try to update rows of a database, the async function doesn't handle different inputs.
It updates the same values for the where part, which always updates only one record. How can I turn local variables for parallel runs of the same function different?

This is my code:

```
exports.run_mercadolibre_jobs = function() {

    var Model  = require('../../models/index').Model;
    var async = require("async");


    var values = {
                attributes: ['environment_hash'],
                raw: true
        };

        Model
            .findAll(values)
            .then(function(accounts) {
                async.map(accounts, function (account) {
                    module.exports.refresh_access_token(account.environment_hash);
                });           
          });

}



exports.refresh_access_token = function(environment_hash) {

    ...

    var env_hash = environment_hash;
    where = { environment_hash: env_hash };

    Model.findOne({where: where}).then(function (account) {
        if (!account) {
            // Item not found, create a new one


        } else {
            // Found an item, update it


            values = {
              refresh_token: body.refresh_token,
              expires_in: expires_in

            };

                        Model.update(values, {where: where})
                            .then(function () {
                                console.log('updated!');
                            })
                            .catch(function (err) {
                                console.log('error on update');
                            });

                }
            });





        }
    });



}
```

Comment: Looking at the code, it's very unlikely that the problem is with the async function. For what I see you can just do `accounts.forEach(function (account) { refresh_access_token(account.environment_hash) });` and still get the same results.

Comment: try console.log enviorment_hash variable and check if it prints the same each time